# how to apply space around property vertically when using flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, space

hello guys I would like to arrange no of list-items vertically with equal space around in a column using `css flex-box` property.
I have tried using

> display: flex;
>       align-content: space-around;

but which does not giving the expected result.Please Help me to fix this .I added my snippet below

```css
#vote-poll{
    display: flex;
    /*flex-direction: column;
    /*justify-content: space-around;*/
    align-content: space-around;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#vote-poll ul>li{
    border:1px solid #000;
    /*width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:20%;*/
    
}
li{
list-style:none;

/*padding:0px;
margin:0px;*/
}
ul {
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="vote-poll" class="border-box">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="party-name-text">
                                        CONG
                                    </div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="party-name-text">
                                        BJP
                                    </div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="party-name-text">
                                        IROM
                                    </div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </li>
                           </ul>
</section>
```

> **Please Note** :- I would like to have an answer Using flex-box property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your flex properties on the `ul` as it is the parent of the items you want to affect. Try this;

```css
#vote-poll{
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#vote-poll ul>li{
    border:1px solid #000; 
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

    /* NEW PROPERTIES HERE */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section id="vote-poll" class="border-box">
    <ul>
         <li>
              <div class="party-name-text">
                 CONG
              </div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
         </li>
         <li>
              <div class="party-name-text">
                 CONG
              </div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
         </li>
         <li>
              <div class="party-name-text">
                 CONG
              </div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```